# No HDR option on KDE Neon plasma 6 - using iGPU instead of dGPU?

Tags: kde, nvidia, display, wayland, kde-neon

I installed KDE Neon about a month ago on my laptop (Gigabyte Aero 15XD) which have an HDR display and an Nvidia RTX 3070. I updated Neon to v6 recently, on Wayland, and hoped to enable HDR, but I don't have the option:

[image]

I just installed the 550 driver using `sudo pkcon install nvidia-driver-550` as some people say it solved the issue, yet still no HDR option visible for me.

I also notice the "About this system" section shows my CPU's chipset instead of my Nvidia GPU, that might be a sign... But I don't know what to do from there.

[image]

In my NVIDIA driver's Prime profiles, I tried both "performance" and "on-demand" options (with reboot at each change) with no visible effect on the HDR option.

[image]